# How will Death of the Endless die?

Tags: comics, the-sandman, vertigo-comics

We have seen that even though The Seven are THE ENDLESS, two of them have died (which is very strange and i am not still clear on that).

When Dream dies, we have seen that Death comes to him and takes him to her realm. Well, I assume that's what she did, though in comics she only touches dreams hand.

I also assume that's what happened to the first Despair i.e. Death takes her to Realm of Death.

Now my question is: Suppose there comes a day when Death dies, how will it happen? How can she take herself to her own realm?

UPDATE:

I just finished reading *Death: The High Cost of Living*

It shows how the living incarnation of death dies and I was amazed to see that SHE TAKE HERSELF TO HER OWN REALM. Well! not exactly. The Death of ENDLESS takes the living incarnation of death (NOT SO ENDLESS :P ) to Death Realm.

Anyone Care to comment on that?

Comment: Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(Sandman)#Fictional_character_biography): "In addition, it is mentioned in Brief Lives that she is the only one of the Endless who may survive the end of this incarnation of the universe."

Comment: I disagree this should be closed. It is potentially answerable, and in fact, I'm satisfied with some of the answers (which are supported with quotes from the source material). This question is not about death (an abstract concept) but about a specific character: Death of the Endless. I don't think the question is opinion based.

Comment: @AndresF., consider what the question really is: "how will the author choose to kill Death?" It's not so much *opinion* as it is *speculation*. Even if you consider foreshadowing or just clues, it's asking for speculation of what will happen in the future.

Comment: Sorry! Guyz. I Didn't know that Stack sites don't allow opinion based questions. Although there should be one. How about stackopinions.com or stackspeculations.com :P

Comment: @AndresF.: I agree with you and I am too satisfied with a couple of answers. In fact, both answers together answer my question to some extent. I guess there isn't a way I can choose both answers??

Comment: @phantom42 That's one interpretation ("how will the author kill this character?", which would require guessing at the future). But I read the question more like "how is Death supposed to die?" which is answerable as long as Death or any other character has discussed the matter. Which apparently they have: read Michael's answer (and the other answers are informative as well!). So it's not speculative IMO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In her own words:

> When the last living thing dies, my job will be finished. I’ll put the chairs on the tables, turn out the lights and lock the universe behind me when I leave.
>
> ("Façade," collected in The Sandman: Dream Country)

So it does not seem that her dying *at all* is something she considers possible. Of course this might be a misconception.

If so, I see two "workarounds" to the question of who takes Death to Death's realm:

- She goes there herself, and in doing so passes on her duties to her successor, or
- She gives her powers to her successor, whose first job would then be to take her to Death's realm.

Answer (score 9):

Unlike the other aspects of the Endless, Death is omnipresent.  When she speaks to Element Girl at the end of *Dream Country* she is simultaneously present in at least four other locations, ferrying others to the land of the dead.

The witch Thessalay has said that Death, alone of the Endless, is not bound by rules.

Given this, it's entirely possible that her incarnations cannot die.

That said, IF she can die, I expect the next incarnation would be immediately selected.  The next incarnation would almost certainly ferry her.

But, as Death herself said, "*When the first living thing existed, I was there. Waiting. When the last living thing dies, my job will be finished. I'll put the chairs on the tables, turn out the lights and lock the universe behind me when I leave.*"

Answer (score 9):

Death, being the incarnation of that state, *is* dead. She enters the realm of Death at will, and when she incarnates as mortal every century, she regains her own personification by dying. As Lovecraft and Martin have said in their own special ways, you cannot die when you are already dead. Death is unique, even among the Endless, for she occupies a paradoxical state - a moving, 'living' manifestation of a concept that embodies the opposite. More so than the other Endless, she is *endless* and will never give up an incarnation, or a 'point of view', as Despair and Dream have done.

It is proven that she never 'dies', as we see her in Gaiman's *The Books of Magic* at the end of the universe, overseeing Destiny's end and sending Timothy Hunter back to his own time before she leaves. She is still very much the same Death that we knew in the Sandman series, showing no changes as she would if, like Dream and Despair, she had changed incarnations during the ages past.

There is also mystery of the six cerements. In 'The Wake', when Eblis O'Shaunessy goes into the secret room of the necropolis that holds the funeral cerements of the Endless, we see six hanging in the room. Only Dream's is clearly identified. Since Despair's death used one, the remaining six *could* be for Destiny, Death, Dream, Destruction, Desire, and Delirium. However, there are other [theories](http://faultsandfractures.com/library/Neil%20Gaiman/Sandman/Annotations%20-%20A%20Complete%20Guide%20to%20the%20Sandman/annotations/sandman.70.draft.html) on the remaining cerements' owners - if a given Endless can 'die' more than once, Despair's cerement should have been replaced, meaning that the absent cerement would be Death's. (There is also the theory that Destruction, having given up his function, no longer would rate a cerement, but I postulate that he's still one of the Endless though he no longer actively pursues the duties of his role; thus, his cerement should still be there waiting for him.)

Since there is no indication that the Endless are limited to giving up only one incarnation during their existence, I posit that the absent cerement shows that Death, alone among her kin, will always be as we know her, and will never seek oblivion.